# How to rename multiple files at once

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, file-rename

I have lots of files, directories and sub-directories at my file system.
For example:

> /path/to/file/test-poster.jpg
>   /anotherpath/my-poster.jpg
>   /tuxisthebest/ohyes/path/exm/bold-poster.jpg

I want to switch all file names from `*-poster.jpg` to `folder.jpg`
I have tried with `sed` and `awk` with no success.
little help?

Comment: I stopped using cli utilities for such task, though that certainly is possible. Take a look at `kfilerename`. It does the job and is pretty mighty.

Comment: Then there's `mmv` that does the trick from a CLI. Last time I looked it was a C source that once compiled allows this. It's also up on my site, http://www.kubat.nl/pages/blogaria/101

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't think it's a duplicate, both questions are fundamentally different in my opinion.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No it's not, the OP wants to name files located in different, specific locations, not all files in a certain map (however deep in the directory structure). Releasing the find command would yield more results than the OP perhaps would like to change.

Comment: @ShellFish Are we reading the same question? He wants to *switch all file names from *-poster.jpg to folder.jpg* in his *lots of files, directories and sub-directories* - and then **as an example** enumerated three.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry, totally misread that :) My bad

Comment: @Elliot, I think it's not exactly the same because the OP wants to rename from `*-poster.jpg` to `folder.jpg`, more than just `-poster.jpg` to `folder.jpg`.

Comment: @j.a. I retracted it, but in that question they were doing the same (e.g. wildcard prefix expansion with rename).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find -name "*poster.jpg" -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%/*}/folder.jpg"' '{}' \;
```

#### Explanation

Here, for each filename matched, executes:

```
sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%/*}/folder.jpg"' '{}'
```

Where `'{}'` is the filename passed as an argument to the *command_string*:

```
mv "$0" "${0%/*}/folder.jpg"
```

So, at the end, `$0` will have the filename.

Finally, `${0%/*}/folder.jpg` expands to the path of the old filename and adds `/folder.jpg`.

#### Example

*Notice I'm replacing `mv` with `echo`*

```
$ find -name "*poster.jpg" -exec sh -c 'echo "$0" "${0%/*}/folder.jpg"' '{}' \;
./anotherpath/my-poster.jpg ./anotherpath/folder.jpg
./path/to/file/test-poster.jpg ./path/to/file/folder.jpg
./tuxisthebest/ohyes/path/exm/bold-poster.jpg ./tuxisthebest/ohyes/path/exm/folder.jpg
```

Comment: Nice, +1 for this: `"${0%/*}/folder.jpg"`. Very elegant scripting!

Answer (score 1):

Try this script, it should rename all the files as required.

```
for i in $(find . -name "*-poster.jpg") ; do folder=`echo $i | awk -F"-poster.jpg" {'print $1'}`; mv -iv $i $folder.folder.jpg; done
```

You can replace . to the directory where these files are placed in the command `find . -name "*-poster.jpg"` in the script. Let me know if it is working fine for you.

Comment: I think the OP wants to rename from `*-poster.jpg` to `folder.jpg`, more than just `-poster.jpg` to `folder.jpg`. Furthermore, the filenames match the pattern `*-poster.jpg` instead of `*.poster.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like

```
find  -name '*poster*' -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "{}"  "$(dirname "{}")"/folder.jpg' \;
```

find all files containing poster == `find  -name '*poster*' -type f`

copy the directory path of the file and store it in a temporary variable and afterwards affix "folder.jpg" to directory path ==    `-exec sh -c 'mv "{}"  "$(dirname "{}")"/folder.jpg'` \;